# Sending multiple attributes in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, laravel-4

I am successfully sending the data through but in the network tab the PUT request gives me a *500 Internal Sever Error*. I am using laravel as my server side framework, and inside my controller I update the data like this.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $player = Player::find($id);
    $player->playerName = $input['playerName'];
    $player->teamID = $input['teamID'];
    $player->points = $input['points'];
    $player->made_one = $input['made_one'];
    $player->made_two = $input['made_two'];
    $player->made_three= $input['made_three'];
    $player->missed_one = $input['missed_one'];
    $player->missed_two = $input['missed_two'];
    $player->missed_three =$input['missed_three'];
    $player->percentage = $input['percentage'];
    $player->assists =$input['assists'];
    $player->rebounds = ['rebounds'];
    $player->steals = $input['steals'];
    $player->turnovers = $input['turnovers'];
    $player->fouls = $input['fouls'];
    $player->feed = $input['feed'];
    $player->save();
}
```

This works very well with backbone.js and that is my javascript framework, I am invoking a `.save()` method when a model is updated, the `$input` attributes above are the attributes inside my model.

The weird thing is if I update less `$input` attributes and set the code like below to do that, I don't get a 500 error.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $player = Player::find($id);
    $player->playerName = $input['playerName'];
    $player->teamID = $input['teamID'];
    $player->points = $input['points'];
    $player->save();
}
```

Both of those functions still update my database table with the right data.

This is the 500 error message

```
{
   "error":{
      "type":"ErrorException",
      "message":"preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array",
      "file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\basketball-app-framework\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php",
      "line":900
   }
}
```

Here is how I am saving it with backbone.js

```
var addThis = parseInt(this.model.get('assists')) + 1;        
this.model.save({assists: addThis});
```

This is how I save points, I add to the `made_one` attribute while also adding to the `points` attribute.

```
var addMake = parseInt(this.model.get('made_one')) + 1;
var addOne = parseInt(this.model.get('points')) + 1;         
this.model.save({made_one: addMake, points: addOne});
```

Comment: I think `$player->rebounds = ['rebounds'];` is not correct.

Comment: Oh I missed that one. There were so many and I was trying to edit them fast. Thanks I bet this fixes it :)

Comment: Wow all that frustration for no reason, it worked!! I am not sure if you can post an answer, but Ill give you points if you do. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You're welcome, I added as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work:

`$player->rebounds = ['rebounds'];` to `$player->rebounds = $input['rebounds'];`